# Script for reading unused values from excel sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, groovy, jython

I have an excel sheet with a column of numbers(has only one column). I'm trying to write a script which reads the number from a spreadsheet but the next time it should not use(read) that value. One number from the column can be used only once.

Seems a simple problem but not sure how exactly to go with this:

My approach is:

Have a step in the script that updates the excel list for flagging(used flag on) i.e., flag on if the number is used and pick a new number with used flag off. Not sure exactly about this approach.

My scripting options are jython, groovy or javascript. I'm trying in jython since i wrote other scripts in the same and they worked fine.

Comment: Create a dictionary/hash and add each number as you read, skipping those already used as keys in the hash.

Comment: This is rather broad and would most likely only result in general suggestions.  If you like jpython, why not start with it, show us some code and by that turn that question into a concrete one for (j)python?